# Tried installing EOS tweaks, failed and now apt update doesn't work

Tags: release-juno

So I wanted to install tweaks and have been at it for the past hour and a half, it keeps giving me this error. I did install software-properties-common and it still didn't change anything.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks

Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily/ubuntu bionic Release         
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done                                                                 
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Now I'm getting an error when I update as well.

```
sudo apt update


Err:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily/ubuntu bionic Release    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]

Reading package lists... Done                                                                 
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Any help on how to properly finish this installation would be amazing, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1) first remove previously added repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks/ppa
```

2) Then add it manually:

- right-click Files icon, select `New Window as Admin` and go to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`;
- in that directory, create an empty file and name it `philip_scott-ubuntu-elementary-tweaks-bionic.list`;
- open that file (i.e. in Code or any other text editor) and paste the following two lines into it:

  `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip.scott/elementary-tweaks/ubuntu bionic main`

  `# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip.scott/elementary-tweaks/ubuntu bionic main`
- save and close the file and try to `sudo apt update`.